# Сохранить выделение(:hover) на последнем выделенном элементе

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

CSS

```
.can_click {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.can_click:hover {
  background-color : #1de9b6;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in list" class="can_click">
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы после отвода курсора за пределы таблицы последний элемент, к которому было применено событие `:hover`, остался выделенным?

Есть какие нибудь простые пути?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант без дополнительных директив, с сохранением индекса текущего элемента.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
    name: "Николай"
  }, {
    name: "Василий"
  }, {
    name: "Сергей"
  }];
  $scope.activeIndex = -1;
  $scope.mouseenter = function(index) {
    $scope.activeIndex = index;
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.can_click {
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
  background-color: #1de9b6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <table ng-controller="myController">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in list" data-ng-class="{'active':$index==activeIndex}" class="can_click" data-ng-mouseenter="mouseenter($index)">
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Решение на angular.js с использованием встроенного jqLite

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [
    {
      name: "Николай"
    },
    {
      name: "Василий"
    },
    {
      name: "Сергей"
    }
  ]
});

myApp.directive('lastHover', function() {
 return {
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   element.on('mouseenter', function(event) {
    element.parent().children('can_click').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');
   });
  }
 }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.can_click td {
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  cursor : pointer;
}
.active {
  background-color : #1de9b6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <table ng-controller="myController">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in list" class="can_click" data-last-hover>
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/sbxLdvbc/)

Comment: а зачем добавлять класс inactive? если только ради прозрачного фона, то он вернется к начальному значению когда уберется класс active

Comment: @Grundy чтобы снять выделение со всех элементов и применить к текущему

Comment: ага, это вместо _removeClass('active')_ получается :)

Comment: @Grundy, вы правы, глупое решение)

Comment: кстати сейчас забавно получается, в итоге все элементы имеют класс active и inactive одновременно, и активность определяется отсутствием класса inactive, а не присутствием _active_

Comment: @Grundy полагаю, это связано с очерёдностью добавления классов или следования классов в CSS

Comment: ну я бы сказал, что это работает в данном случае только из-за правильного порядка классов :)

Comment: @Grundy исправил)

Comment: К чертям ломает разметку. С какого то черта таблица склеилась в одну строку.  Может конечно я что-то накосячил, но другой ответ заработал "из коробки". Но в целом заявленное поведение реализуется, потому плюс в карму :)

Comment: @rjhdby Возможно, из-за стилей, свойство display: table-cell; :)

Comment: не не не, просто в первом из ответов, были ячейки, а тут строки с одной ячейкой

Comment: @Romanzhivo, кстати ставить на нативные строки _table-cell_ это сильно

Comment: @Grundy кстати да :) Поправил, так, наверно, более правильно

Answer (score 1):

Можно через jquery:

```js
$(".can_click td").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".can_click td").css("background-color", "#fff");
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
})
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.can_click {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="can_click">
    <td>11111111</td>
    <td>222222</td>
    <td>3333333</td>
    <td>44444444</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="can_click">
    <td>11111111</td>
    <td>222222</td>
    <td>3333333</td>
    <td>44444444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [tag:angularjs]

Comment: @Qwertiy ТС просил простые пути.....

Comment: @C.Raf.T, использование библиотеки, которая даже может быть не подключена в проект, не совсем простой путь

Comment: Да в принципе jquery не сложно подключить и в целом решение достаточно короткое, но есть лучше, как оказалось :)